# Java: Efficent / lean performance counter for 10 seconds average

Tags: java

For a current project, i need to track various counters and display a "operation / s" stats. In order to have a somewhat stable view, I would like to evaluate the past 10 seconds.

A bulletproof, failsave attempt would be to store a list, adding the exact date per operation - and before updating the counter, remove every date that is older than 10 seconds - and finally count it.

However, for some counters, we are talking about 25k ops/s - so not an ideal approach to store and compare that much dates for a simple number to display.

So, I created an `Integer[10]` and increasing the count of the `nth` element by simply doing a `array[(new Date().getTime() % 10)] +=1` upon every action. Whenever the mod overflows to the next second, i'm resetting that index's value to 0, first.

tiny issue (1) with that: Some counters do not produce a value per second, but maybe 2000 every 3rd second. Then, a reset would be missed and the counter would be wrong.

So, I thought about using a (per second) timer task to reset the positions even if no action happens for more than a second - however, this does not 100% guarantee an execution every 1000ms - based on the internal clock and cpu load it might be more or less than 1000ms, causing a reset to be missed every now and then. (When it will jump from second `xx:xx:05.998` to `xx:xx:07.002` because that iteration took 1004ms)

Any idea, how to "reset" the count-array entries reliable without adding too much overhead?
(Well, not trusting 1000ms iterations may already be a bit overkill)

Simple code example:

```
private int useMod = 0;
private int countXModTen = new int[10];

public synchronized void notifyCountX(){
    int newMod = (new Date()).getSeconds() % 10;

    if (newMod != useMod) {
        //reset if overflow -> Issue if no message for a second.
        countXModTen[newMod] = 1; 
        useMod = newMod;
    } else {
        countXModTen[useMod] += 1;
    }
}
```

Moving the reset to a timerTask leads to Issue number 2, in terms of inaccuracy :(

Comment: Why not ArrayDeque?

Comment: Why not Instant?

Comment: What is a "second"? A calendar second or a rolling second?

Answer (score 0):

For the time beeing I found a workaround:

- I'm running the timer task every 500ms rather than every 1000ms
- The task itself checks, if it has already been executed "this second".
- So in the case of a unlucky overflow, it will still have one execution in second `n` and 3 runs / 2 "skips" in second `n+1`

something like

```
private int evalMod = 0;
 
 ...
 
 this.timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int newEvalSecond = (new Date()).getSeconds() % 10;

        //only perform reset if an overflow happens.
        if (newEvalSecond != evalMod) {
            evalMod = newEvalSecond;
            
            //evaluate all 10 entries, reset index of "evalMod"
        }
    }
};

timer.schedule(timerTask, 500, 500);
```

but still wondering, if there might be more elegant solutions.

Still not the final story, because, when one reset-iteration (2 timer iterations) is shorted to 998ms, the next call is actually ~ 1500ms, so not a "per second" update then. Could ofc. shorten the frequency to ~ 50ms to minimize the offsetting.

edit: yeah, running it every 50ms works quite nice - but still feels a bit hacky in terms of optimized resource usage. (having +/-50ms offset for a 10.000 ms period doesn't really matter)

Comment: `TimerTask` and`Timer` have been supplanted by [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) years ago, as noted in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

> track various counters and display a "operation / s" stats

Perhaps I’ve misunderstood the problem, but you seem to be overcomplicating matters.

### `AtomicLong`

Create an `AtomicLong` instance. Make that instance available to your operation code.

On every run, that operation code increments the `AtomicLong`.

It is crucial that you only ever instantiate the `AtomicLong` once. Mark it `final` so the instance can never be replaced. Assign the instance in the declaration line so the object exists before any other code can access the reference variable.

```
public final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong ( 0 ) ;
```

### `Runnable`

Define a task (`Runnable`/`Callable`) that accesses that same `AtomicLong`.

The task retrieves the current value while simultaneously setting it to zero. Call [`getAndSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#getAndSet(long)).

### `ScheduledExecutorService`

Submit an instance of this task to a single-threaded `ScheduledExecutorService`. Schedule that task to run every ten seconds.

### Time-keeping

Understand that a conventional implementation of Java on conventional hardware will *not* keep perfect time.

Your task will generally run very close to ten seconds, but not exactly. Also, a significant delay might occur during a [stop-the-world](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection#Stop-the-world_vs._incremental_vs._concurrent) garbage collection within the JVM. Similarly, a delay might occur if the machine is overburdened to the point where the host OS cannot adequately schedule execution time for the thread backing your executor schedule.

More perfect time-keeping is only possible with a real-time computer running a real-time OS hosting an implementation of [real-time Java](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java).

### Reporting results

So, you may want to track when exactly your background count-retrieving task runs.

I would use `java.time.Instant#now` to capture the current moment as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC. In Java 9+, the current moment is captured to a resolution of microseconds, though `Instant` resolves to nanoseconds.

You might collect these results in a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395). Post them to a queue for handling.

```
public record OperationCountReport ( long count , Instant start , Instant end ) {}
```

You can calculate [elapsed time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html):

```
Duration elapsed = Duration.between ( start , end ) ;
```

### Example code

```java
package work.basil.example.datetime;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class OperationsPerSecond
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        final AtomicLong operationsCounter = new AtomicLong ( 0 );
        try (
                ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor ( ) ;
        )
        {
            ses.scheduleAtFixedRate ( new OperationCountReportingTask ( operationsCounter ) , 10 , 10 , TimeUnit.SECONDS );
            try (
                    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor ( ) ;
            )
            {
                for ( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )
                {
                    System.out.println ( "sumbitting operating task" );
                    executorService.submit ( new OperatingTask ( operationsCounter ) );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

record OperationsCountReport( long count , Instant start , Instant end ) { }

class OperationCountReportingTask implements Runnable
{
    private final AtomicLong operationsCounter;
    private Instant lastReported = Instant.now ( );

    public OperationCountReportingTask ( final AtomicLong operationsCounter ) { this.operationsCounter = operationsCounter; }

    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        OperationsCountReport report = new OperationsCountReport ( this.operationsCounter.getAndSet ( 0 ) , this.lastReported , Instant.now ( ) );
        this.lastReported = report.end ( );
        long operationsPerSecond = report.count ( ) / Duration.between ( report.start ( ) , report.end ( ) ).toSeconds ( );
        System.out.println ( "report = " + operationsPerSecond + " operations per second. Detail: " + report );
    }
}

class OperatingTask implements Runnable
{
    final AtomicLong operationsCounter;
    final Instant started = Instant.now ( );

    public OperatingTask ( final AtomicLong operationsCounter )
    {
        this.operationsCounter = operationsCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        System.out.println ( "running run method" );
        while ( Duration.between ( started , Instant.now ( ) ).toMinutes ( ) < 1 )  // Run just over one minute.
        {
            // To simulate actual operations doing work, sleep for a random amount of milliseconds.
            try { Thread.sleep ( ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 750 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
//            System.out.println ( "Operation performed by thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread ( ).threadId ( ) + " at " + Instant.now ( ) );
            operationsCounter.incrementAndGet ( ); // Count each operation performed by this Runnable.
        }
    }
}
```

When run.

```
sumbitting operating task
sumbitting operating task
sumbitting operating task
running run method
running run method
running run method
report = 7 operations per second. Detail: OperationsCountReport[count=78, start=2024-01-07T00:02:23.628089Z, end=2024-01-07T00:02:33.635889Z]
report = 9 operations per second. Detail: OperationsCountReport[count=83, start=2024-01-07T00:02:33.635889Z, end=2024-01-07T00:02:43.633431Z]
report = 8 operations per second. Detail: OperationsCountReport[count=76, start=2024-01-07T00:02:43.633431Z, end=2024-01-07T00:02:53.630240Z]
report = 8 operations per second. Detail: OperationsCountReport[count=72, start=2024-01-07T00:02:53.630240Z, end=2024-01-07T00:03:03.629794Z]
report = 8 operations per second. Detail: OperationsCountReport[count=80, start=2024-01-07T00:03:03.629794Z, end=2024-01-07T00:03:13.632380Z]
report = 7 operations per second. Detail: OperationsCountReport[count=73, start=2024-01-07T00:03:13.632380Z, end=2024-01-07T00:03:23.643556Z]
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. I don't think the AtomicLong alone can resolve this. Handling an exact "snapshot" of the past second (or past 10 seconds) would be possible with that - but I want a "floating average" of the past 10 seconds. That means - every second - I need to be able to drop out the "counts" that are now older than 10 seconds. ... Hmm, what I could do is to start "counting" a new instance every second and always evaluate the one, that now reached it's 10 second age.

Comment: AtomicInteger is sufficient, unless you live in a world where more than 2 billion operations can be performed per second.

Comment: @Bohemian I think on modern machines we can afford the extra 32 bits.

Comment: @Bohemian ONE is not sufficent "logically", (for a floating average). It can tell only how much counts are there per KNOWN period. (Thus, I went with 10 of them)

Comment: @dognose Sorry, I really cannot comprehend the complexity of what you seem to want. `"Operations per second" = "Count of operations over 10 seconds" / 10`

Comment: @BasilBourque it's all about definition (Business Side) - `Ops / s` and a `floating average over 10s` is not the same: Take a 3 second example and this data-sequence: `[..,0,0,9,9,0, ...]`. Evaluation per second would display `0/s, 0/s, 9/s, 9/s, 0/s` - floating average over 3 seconds would display `0/s, 0/s, 3/s, 6/s, 6/s`. (Not that it is more accurate - but its purpose is to flatten out highs and lows)

Comment: @BasilBourque Oh, `Moving Average` would be the correct translation, not floating. Shame on me https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6d/Lissage_sinus_bruite_moyenne_glissante.svg

Answer (score 0):

@Basil Bourque s answer helped me to rethink the issue. I've now managed to create a working version with some benefits:

1. It doesn't require a too frequent timer task (of whatever kind) - a usual 1000ms evaluation +/- natural deviation is good enough, there won't be any issues with missed resets anymore.
2. It does no longer require (expensive) Date-Objects to be constructed for every "count"

So, rather than trying to keep distinct historic values of each seconds within the past 10 seconds, i've now switched to creating 10 variables, that continiously increment for 10 seconds, starting with 1 second offsets.

Thus, every second I have one count for the past 10 seconds, which is easy to reset and calculate with.

- There is an array of length 10, using AtomicInts to avoid concurrency issues.
- Timer is running every second.
- For the first 10 seconds, it will create one new atomic int, adding it to the array.
- The incoming trigger will increment *all* positions of the array, that are not null.
- For the first 10 seconds, evaluation will be performed by `position 0` / `secondsPassed`
- For second 10+ always `position p` / `10.0` will be my desired average.

Code (removed overhead):

```
private AtomicLong persistentCount = new AtomicLong(0);
private AtomicInteger[] messages = {new AtomicInteger(0), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null};
private AtomicLong[] bytes = {new AtomicLong(0), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null };
private boolean bufferFilled=false;
private int bf = 0;
private int p = 1;
private Timer timer = new Timer();
private TimerTask timerTask;

private PerformanceUtils(){

    this.timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //if the buffer is filled, evaluate at position p divided by 10
            //if not yet filled, evaluate pos 0 divided by p
            double mps, bps;

            if (bf == 9){
                mps = messages[p].getAndSet(0) / 10.0;
                bps = bytes[p].getAndSet(0) / 10.0;

                p++;

                if (p == 10)
                    p=0;

            }else{
                mps = messages[0].get() / (p * 1.0);
                bps = bytes[0].get() / (p * 1.0);
            }

            //if the buffer is not yet filled, unlock one more counter
            if (bf < 9){
                messages[p] = new AtomicInteger(0);
                bytes[p] = new AtomicLong(0);

                p++;
                bf++;

                if (p == 10){
                    p=0;
                }
            }
            
            //display values
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000,1000);
}

public void notifyMessageReceived(long byteCount){
    for (int i=0; i<=bf; i++){
        messages[i].getAndAdd(1);
        bytes[i].getAndAdd(byteCount);
    }

    persistentCount.getAndAdd(1);
}
```

debugwise it looks as expected and after 10 seconds of runtime, peaks and drops do no longer cause a massive change in the calculated rate, as a per-second evaluation would do.

Example with some smaller numbers due to nighttime:
First 10 seconds: Array-Positions are "unlocked", evaluation is always position 0 / time:

```
    [478, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
 => [478, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null] => 478.0
    [1005, 527, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
 => [1005, 527, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null] => 502.5
    [1628, 1150, 623, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
 => [1628, 1150, 623, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null] => 542.6666666666666
    [1767, 1289, 762, 139, null, null, null, null, null, null]
 => [1767, 1289, 762, 139, 0, null, null, null, null, null] => 441.75
    [1782, 1304, 777, 154, 15, null, null, null, null, null]
 => [1782, 1304, 777, 154, 15, 0, null, null, null, null] => 356.4
    [1807, 1329, 802, 179, 40, 25, null, null, null, null]
 => [1807, 1329, 802, 179, 40, 25, 0, null, null, null] => 301.1666666666667
    [1842, 1364, 837, 214, 75, 60, 35, null, null, null]
 => [1842, 1364, 837, 214, 75, 60, 35, 0, null, null] => 263.14285714285717
    [1869, 1391, 864, 241, 102, 87, 62, 27, null, null]
 => [1869, 1391, 864, 241, 102, 87, 62, 27, 0, null] => 233.625
    [1896, 1418, 891, 268, 129, 114, 89, 54, 27, null]
 => [1896, 1418, 891, 268, 129, 114, 89, 54, 27, 0] => 210.66666666666666
    [1930, 1452, 925, 302, 163, 148, 123, 88, 61, 34]
 => [0, 1452, 925, 302, 163, 148, 123, 88, 61, 34] => 193.0
```

From Second 10+, always the oldest entry (about 10 seconds, surprise) is evaluated and then reset to 0:

```
    [48, 1500, 973, 350, 211, 196, 171, 136, 109, 82]
 => [48, 0, 973, 350, 211, 196, 171, 136, 109, 82] => 150.0
    [62, 14, 987, 364, 225, 210, 185, 150, 123, 96]
 => [62, 14, 0, 364, 225, 210, 185, 150, 123, 96] => 98.7
    [107, 59, 45, 409, 270, 255, 230, 195, 168, 141]
 => [107, 59, 45, 0, 270, 255, 230, 195, 168, 141] => 40.9
    [134, 86, 72, 27, 297, 282, 257, 222, 195, 168]
 => [134, 86, 72, 27, 0, 282, 257, 222, 195, 168] => 29.7
    [157, 109, 95, 50, 23, 305, 280, 245, 218, 191]
 => [157, 109, 95, 50, 23, 0, 280, 245, 218, 191] => 30.5
    [188, 140, 126, 81, 54, 31, 311, 276, 249, 222]
 => [188, 140, 126, 81, 54, 31, 0, 276, 249, 222] => 31.1
    [233, 185, 171, 126, 99, 76, 45, 321, 294, 267]
 => [233, 185, 171, 126, 99, 76, 45, 0, 294, 267] => 32.1
    [258, 210, 196, 151, 124, 101, 70, 25, 319, 292]
 => [258, 210, 196, 151, 124, 101, 70, 25, 0, 292] => 31.9
    [295, 247, 233, 188, 161, 138, 107, 62, 37, 329]
 => [295, 247, 233, 188, 161, 138, 107, 62, 37, 0] => 32.9
```

Never thought getting a floating-average (with a minimal memory footprint) from live-data is so much effort :0)